# Is there a cuda function to copy a row from a Matrix in column major?

Tags: cuda, cublas

I have a device matrix U of dimensions MxN in column major ordering. Now I'd like to extract the row K into a vector u. Is there a function to accomplish this? Note the copy would need to take into account an offset of K and a stride of M.

I was looking at the function [cudaMemcpy2D](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375) but it rings no bells, coming from a more LAPACK style API I don't understand what these pitch parameters are, why are they not called simply rows and cols or M and N?

Comment: What about using `cublas<t>copy()` with a proper use of `incx` and `incy`, related to the row length?

Comment: The width and pitch (padded width) are given in bytes because cudaMalloc2D() and cudaMemcpy2D() are typeless - they have no idea what kind of data resides in the array.  NVIDIA decided to use a size in bytes rather than pass an extra parameter with the element size.  It's more of a precedent in the graphics world (QuickDraw, DirectX) than the BLAS world, where there are fewer types and the element size can be inferred from the subroutine name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
cublas<t>copy(handle, N, U+K, M, u, 1);
```

as

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<assert.h>

#include<cublas_v2.h>

/***********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECKING */
/***********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);     
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/*************************/
/* cuBLAS ERROR CHECKING */
/*************************/
#ifndef cublasSafeCall
#define cublasSafeCall(err)     __cublasSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#endif

inline void __cublasSafeCall(cublasStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if( CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUBLAS error in file '%s', line %d\n \nerror %d \nterminating!\n",__FILE__, __LINE__,err); 
        getch(); cudaDeviceReset(); assert(0); 
    }
}

int main() {

    const int M = 5;
    const int N = 4;
    const int K = 2;

    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&handle));

    float* U = (float*)malloc(M*N*sizeof(float));
    float* d_U; 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_U,M*N*sizeof(float)));

    float* u = (float*)malloc(M*sizeof(float));
    float* d_u;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_u,N*sizeof(float)));

    for (int j=0; j<N; j++) 
        for (int i=0; i<M; i++) 
            U[j*M+i] = (float)(i*j); // Column-major ordering

    printf("K-th row - Input\n");
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++) printf("U(K,%i) =  %f\n",j,U[j*M+K]);
    printf("\n\n");

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_U,U,M*N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cublasSafeCall(cublasScopy(handle, N, d_U+K, M, d_u, 1));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(u,d_u,N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("K-th row - Output\n");
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++) printf("u(%i) =  %f\n",j,u[j]);

    getchar();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Farzad noted, the memory access pattern for the operation you want is inefficient, but other than that, what you want can be accomplished with a call to cudaMemcpy2D (assuming u and U are of type int):

```
 cudaMemcpy2D((void*)u, sizeof(int), (void*)(U+K), sizeof(int)*M, sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first part is no. The memory inside the GPU is linear, like the host side. If you want to access only row elements of a 2D matrix that is saved in column-major order, it  would be costly because of non-coalesced accesses. Since GPU memory is configured in segments, every access to an element requires fetching not only the element itself but also the neighboring elements in the segment, which in column-major ordering happens to be mostly elements of the column the element resides in. While if you store your matrix in row-major order and access elements of a row, GPU tries to merge simultaneous memory requests to minimum segment transactions.
[`cudaMallocPitch`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g80d689bc903792f906e49be4a0b6d8db.html), which is preferred for saving 2D data, pads the memory allocation so the starting address of each and every row/column with length `width` reside in the starting address of a segment. As a result, when you access all elements of a row/column, fetched segments would be minimized. The cost of using this method is wasting memory space.

Comment: The answer to the first part is _yes_. It may be inefficient, but cublas<T>copy or cudaMemcpy2D can copy a single row, as noted in other answers.